# How to forecast the optimum price increase to increase revenue

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, econometrics

My company is evaluating whether a price increase will be profitable across each of its different products. I want to know how to use and which model to use to estimate the optimal price increase. This is in the Retail space and will be a one-time price increase (last price increase was 2 years ago). I do have daily data of each product's sales at the price point.

Comment: Is there any price variation in your data?